# Как записать данные в массив js из json?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть файл data.json c таким содержимым. Заполняется файл с помощью некоего php кода

```
{"тест1":[15455430,12333,1123],"тест2":[14382215,655567,55556777]}
```

Я накатал js скрипт который забирает данные и выводит их на график. Он действительно выводит на график мои данные.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            val = Object.values(data);

            var keys = [];
                for(var k in data) keys.push(k);

            var series = [];

            series.push({
              name: keys[0],
              data: val[0].map(function(item){return parseInt(item);})            
            });

            series.push({
              name: keys[1],
              data: val[1].map(function(item){return parseInt(item);})            
            });

            // console.log(series);
            
            Highcharts.chart('container2', {

                series: series

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Вопрос. Могу ли я использовать цикл for в js чтобы записать данные в series используя только один series.push? Если да, то как это можно сделать? Сам пробовал, но не силен в js :(

Вводные данные: В series.push ключ name должен содержать текст "тест1" из json, а ключ name содержит в себе данные 15455430,12333,1123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let test = {
  "тест1": [15455430, 12333, 1123],
  "тест2": [14382215, 655567, 55556777]
};

let series = [];

for (const [name, data] of Object.entries(test)) {
    series.push({ name, data });
//    series.push({
//        name: name,
//        data: data
//    });
}

console.log(series);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, вопрос решен! :)

Comment: @ИгнатийШиленин отлично)) Если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку напротив ответа))

Comment: Да, жду чтобы нажать:))

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен притензий нет.

Предложу немного другой вариант с map. И пушить ничего никуда не надо

```js
let test = {
  "тест1": [15455430, 12333, 1123],
  "тест2": [14382215, 655567, 55556777]
};

let series = Object.entries(test).map(i=>({name:i[0], data:i[1]})); 
    

console.log(series);
```

Comment: Во, а я думал, как мапу к объекту прикрутить. У массива же есть)) Забыл))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да конечно, норм повторить и вспомнить